# How to show text side of a table in html

Tags: html, html-table

Normally in html text is showing below the table. Even the if table size is little. How can I show text at the left or right side of a table in html?

Answer (score 0):

Its more about CSS, you need to set display to `inline-block` or equivalent to show text adjacent to table.

```
<table style="display:inline-block;">
   ...
</table>
<span>Hello</span>
```